# Saving several EditText after program closes

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to make a Character sheet for a DnD like game. The point is to take user input and store it for future viewing and changing. Maybe I'm looking for a solution that doesn't exists but I want the EditTexts to stay the way they are if the user closes the app or just goes back to the title screen. Following is part of the xml file for the user input, the java file is basically blank

```
**<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:background="@drawable/scroll_s">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/name"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/player"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@id/player"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"/>
        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/pts_total"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/unspent_pts"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/pts_total"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/unspent_pts"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:inputType="number"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/ht"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/wt"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/age"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal">
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/height"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/weightt"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@id/age"
                android:inputType="number"
                android:layout_weight="1"/>
        </LinearLayout>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/size_mod"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:inputType="text"/>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/appearance"/>
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/appearance"
            android:inputType="text"/>





    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>**
```

Java file

```
package com.example.mapuchii.gurps;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;

public class Character_activity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_character_redo);
}

@Override
protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    // Read values from the "savedInstanceState"-object and put them in your textview
}

@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    // Save the values you need from your textview into "outState"-object
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is one example:

```
public class Character_activity extends AppCompatActivity {

  private EditText playerEditText;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_character_redo);
    playerEditText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.player);
  }

  @Override
  protected void onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onRestoreInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    playerEditText.setText(savedInstanceState.getString("SavedPlayer", "");
  }

  @Override
  protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString("SavedPlayer", playerEditText.getText().toString());

    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
  }
}
```

This will save your text over an orientation change. If you want to save it when your process is killed then you need to look at `SharedPreferences` instead of a `Bundle`.

http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/shared-preferences.html

Comment: Thank you!
Your answer along with this one helped me solve it!
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18724882/saving-data-in-edittext-when-hitting-back-button